# iptables to get public ip on virtual box's 2nd interface

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp

I am running a custom *linux* image on *Virtual box*.  Also,I am using a *USB*-to-*Ethernet* connector from my Laptop to connect other clients. In the network setting, I have used bridge adapter for both interfaces i.e. *eth0* and *Asix* (usb-to-ethernet).  When I am running virtual box, *eth0* is getting public *IP* like *10.x.x.x* but *eth1*(USB-to_eth) is not getting any *IP*.

I tried to run `udhcpc` on *eth1* to get *IP* using *dhcp* but failed. Moreover, I assigned *eth1* some *IP* in the same range as *eth0* with *eth0* as route. But still, no packets are reaching to *eth0* from *eth1*. I tested the same by pinging other public *IP* via *eth1* interface like `ping -I eth1 10.x.x.x` but failed.

I also tried `iptables` rules like below with:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces doesn't show anything as there is no such file.

Comment: If you have both them bridged, it is the bridge interface that will get the IP. Add to the question `/etc/network/interfaces` please.

Comment: And `brctl show` please

Comment: Two thoughts. 1. `eth0` should not be getting any address; this might be a limitation of VirtualBox. 2. Your `10.*` isn't a public IP. Please confirm whether this address is a NAT one from Virtual Box or whether it's the right addressing for your host's LAN. It something else.

Comment: cat /etc/network/interfaces doesn't show anything as there is no such file. eth0 is getting IP(10.x.x.x).  Here public IP I mean company's network which is in the range of my laptop(10.x.x.x).

Comment: The main reason is I want to connect another client to eth1(USB-to_ethernet) and I want that client to get Public IP. DHCP pcakets are reaching to eth1 but not getting forwarded to eth0. same case as before.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I tried having both them bridged and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Excellent. Next time add the Linux distribution to the post, you do not have /etc/network/interfaces as you probably are not using a Debian derivate.